# Ansible: check async_status on multiple jobs with and without results

Tags: ansible

I have three Ansible tasks for downloading various resources. Two of them are created using a loop, so, they have the key `results` and return lists of objects and one returns just one object that has the key `ansible_job_id`.

How can I iterate over all of them in one check job statuses task?   I've tried `with_nested` but got the error

> 'list object' has no attribute 'ansible_job_id'

```yaml
- name: Check download job statuses
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 12
  delay: 10
  with_nested:
    - list1.results
    - list2.results
    - object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to make one list with all the elements having the `ansible_job_id` key.

Concatenation of lists is as simple, in Jinja, as adding them — with the `+` operator.
So, your task ends up being:

```yaml
- name: Check download job statuses
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 12
  delay: 10
  loop: "{{ list1.results + list2.results + [object] }}"
```